# Hide faces of instanced mesh

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm making a Minecraft clone (yes, another person doing it) for fun using three.js.
There's a lot of answers explaining how to hide faces of a BoxGeometry or BufferGeometry and I've accomplished that when I was using them.

However, I've switched to instanced meshes to cut down on draw calls (1 per chunk rather than 1 per block, which used BoxGeometry).

The docs specify that the geometry in the instanced mesh must be the same, however, is it possible to modify it in some way to remove faces?

I want to remove faces that are facing each other, because they won't be seen any way.

Here's the basic example of creating the indexed mesh:

```js
this.material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial()
this.mesh = new THREE.InstancedMesh(geometry, this.material, allBlocks.length)

allBlocks.forEach((block, index) => {
  const matrix = new THREE.Matrix4()
  const quaternion = new THREE.Quaternion()
  quaternion.setFromEuler(new THREE.Euler(0, 0, 0))

  matrix.compose(block.position, quaternion, new THREE.Vector3(1, 1, 1))
  this.mesh.setMatrixAt(index, matrix)

  const color = new THREE.Color()
  const name = blockColors[randRange(0, blockColors.length - 1)]
  color.setColorName(name)
  this.mesh.setColorAt(index, color)
})
```

`geometry` is an array of geometries (planes) that have been merged using `BufferGeometryUtils.mergeGeometries`. This is left over from when I wasn't using instanced meshes and each block had a mesh. I was able to hide a face by not adding one of the plane geometries to the merge.

`allBlocks` only contains blocks that would be visible (no block that is obscured by another on every side).

If this isn't possible, is there a way to achieve this by using instanced buffer geometry?

Comment: The question is: What are you really saving by removing faces? Are there other performance enhancements you can make that will have a bigger impact? For example, can you build your chunk such that only "surface blocks" (instances) are rendered? When a block is added/removed, evaluate whether the surrounding blocks should be added/removed from the list of renderable instances. For a solid chunk, this would remove 38,416 blocks (instances).